# Does $|Tf|=T|f|$ hold for positive operators?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra.

We have the usual absolute value:

$$|a|:=\sqrt{a^*a},$$

and the cone of positive elements:

$$A^+:=\{a\in A:\exists \,b\in A, a=b^*b\}.$$

An operator $T\in B(A)$ is said to be positive if $T(A^+)\subset A^+$.

> Does it hold that $|Tf|=T|f|$ for positive $T$?.

**Context:**

I don't have any reason to believe this but I have a $T$-invariant finite trace $h\in A^{'}$ ($h\circ T=h$) and if I have the above I have

$$\|Tf\|_{\mathcal{L}^1}=h(|Tf|)=h(T|f|)=h(|f|)=\|f\|_{\mathcal{L}^1},$$
which would be useful to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, we do not have $|Tf | = T |f|$.
To see this, consider the $2 \times 2$-matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $T$ be taking the transpose of a matrix.
Then $T$ is a positive operator, but for $f = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{matrix} \right)$ we have
\begin{align*}
|Tf| =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{matrix} \right) \neq \left( \begin{matrix} \sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix} \right) = T|f|.
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice counter-example, thank you (you had them the wrong way around so I just edited that).

Answer (score 4):

As Hetebrij pointed out, it's false.  On a positive note, there is a nice (and useful!) characterisation of the linear maps that preserve the absolute value.

> **Theorem** *(Gardner 1979)*: For a linear map $\varphi\colon A \to B$ of C* algebras the following are equivalent
>
> 1. $\varphi$ preserves absolute values
> 2. $\varphi$ is positive and $\varphi(1)\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$ for all $a,b\in A$.
> 3. $\varphi$ is $2$-positive and disjoint (i.e. if $x,y \geq 0$ and $xy=0$ then $\varphi(x)\varphi(y)=0$).

http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1979-076-02/S0002-9939-1979-0537087-0/S0002-9939-1979-0537087-0.pdf

With Gardner's Theorem we can prove the following characterisation of the positive *unital* maps that preserve absolute value.

> **Proposition**. (WW) For a positive *unital* map $\varphi\colon A \to B$ between *von Neumann algebras* the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\varphi$ preserves absolute values
> 2. $\varphi$ is a $*$-homomorphism
> 3. $\varphi$ preserves projections and is $2$-positive
> 4. $\varphi$ preserves ranges and is $2$-positive

( Follows from Proposition 47 of  http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/57/9/10.1063/1.4961526 )

Comment: Excellent - this may be very useful thank you.